# how to hide console window of another executable?

Tags: c#

Our C# application will launch a console application executable by doing this: `Process correctionProcess = Process.Start(exePath, rawDataFileName);`

Customer wants to hide that console window which is from their application. Is that possible for us to do that?

Comment: Do you have the source of the EXE you're launching?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create the `Process` with `ProcessStartInfo`, where the [`CreateNoWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow.aspx) and [`UseShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx) properties are set to true and false respectively.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath);
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.Arguments = rawDataFileName;

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: The OP asked to hide the console window of another exe created by another application. This will only work if he is able to wrap the application with this caller. Also, applications do not always respond to the CreateNoWindow parameter.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey - the OP posts a _clear_ sample of using `Process.Start`. I can only assume that this is the usage scenario.

Comment: Good point.  I assumed the Process.Start was for his application exe, and he wanted to hide another application exe.  Question is unclear, but obviously you were right as the OP chose your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I used recently to do exactly that:

ProcessStartInfo is in System.Diagnotics

```
 ProcessStartInfo startInfo          = new ProcessStartInfo();
 startInfo.CreateNoWindow            = true;
 startInfo.UseShellExecute           = false;
 startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput    = true;
 startInfo.RedirectStandardError     = true;
 startInfo.FileName                  = "your_app.exe";
 startInfo.WindowStyle               = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 startInfo.Arguments                 = "args"

    //Launch the process.
 process = Process.Start( startInfo );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.  What you will have to do is set up the Process in the following manner:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = rawDataFileName;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.CreateNoWindow = true;
// p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the win API to hide any console window as long as you know it's name.  Re-using my MSDN post...

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


class Program
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    const int SW_HIDE = 0;
    const int SW_SHOW = 5;

    static void Main()
    {
        string caption = @"file:///";
        caption += System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        caption = caption.Replace('\\','/');

        // replace 'caption' with the exact caption of your console window
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, caption);
        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            #region your code
            Process myProcess = new Process();
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = " /c notepad.exe";
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            myProcess.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            myProcess.Start();
            #endregion

            ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE); // Hide console window
            myProcess.WaitForExit();//OPTIONAL
            //ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW); // Reshow console window (OPTIONAL)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: By "From their application" I believe the OP means another process. In which case Process parameters will not be of use. The title alsp specifies "from another exe".

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
private void StartHiddenConsoleApp( string exePath, string args )
{
    var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

    psi.Arguments = args;
    psi.CreateNoWindow = false;
    psi.ErrorDialog = false;
    psi.FileName = exePath;
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    var p = Process.Start( psi );
}
```

Comment: You'd actually have to set  psi.CreateNoWindow to true, not false.